# Data Loader export of ContactHistory records ignores timezone setting in version 36

Tags: data-loader

I noticed today using v36 of data loader against a Winter '17 Salesforce org that export of data fields in the ContactHistory object (OldValue/NewValue) was ignoring the timezone setting - unless the BulkAPI option was checked.  So in version v36 the only way to get timezone converted dates was with the Bulk API option.

I upgraded to the current version v38.0.1 and that works as expected i.e. the date values exported are the same regardless of whether the Bulk API option is checked.

This could cause data corruption issues.

Potentially applications which integrate with Salesforce via the API might experience the same thing.

Has anyone else experienced integration tools using the v36 API not doing the right thing with the timezone offsets?

Comment: Is this actually a question? Is it meant to be a Q&A? If you've already answered your own question, you should rewrite this post above to be a *question*, and post the fix as an *answer*.

Comment: Fair comment.  My question is whether this is an issue with the v36 API talking to a current Winter '17 v38 org.  I can't tell whether the issue was always there with Data Loader or whether this is new (as the orgs are all updated now).  At the same client this week (different person, different PC) we had a similar issue with CrmFusions DemandTools merging records and offseting the merged date by a day.  So has anyone else noticed existing integration tools which are using the v36 API not doing the right things with date timezone offsets?